# How do I do a multiple line verbatim string in Delphi/Pascal

Tags: string, delphi

In c# you can use multiline literal strings to have a string which spans a physical line break in the sourcecode e.g.

```
var someHtml = @"<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center" class="txsbody">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="15%" class="ttxb">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="85%" class="ttxb"><b>COMPANY NAME</b></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>";
```

but how to do this in delphi without using string concatenation, not so much for performance but for looking visually as nice as in c# instead of

```
Result :        = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center" class="txsbody">';
Result : Result + '<tbody>';
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How to do this in delphi without using string concatenation?

You cannot. There is no support for multi-line literals. Concatenation is the only option.

However, your Delphi code performs the concatenation at runtime. It's far better to do it at compile time. So instead of:

```
Result := 'foo';
Result := Result + 'bar';
```

write

```
Result := 'foo' +
          'bar';
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that answer... however this is sad sad news

Comment: How is it sad? `Result := 'foo' + 'bar';` will be done at compile time, so it will result in one single constant, `'foobar'`. I have coded very long constant strings this way, and they do not take up any runtime. They are just there, compiled in as static text. Your way, `Result := 'foo'; Result := Result + 'bar';` is slow, because it concatenates at runtime..

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Max is sad because he does not want to have to concatenate. He'd like to use a multi-line literal.

Comment: Hmmm... Is that all? That is complaining  at a high level. <g>

Comment: Max, think of this as multiline-literal syntax that is easy to read, albeit harder to write. .  Are you happy now?  If you would like to automatically turn a lot of literal text into this syntax, it would be easy to write a little tool to "paste multi-line syntax literal".

Comment: Yes I'm sad because I wanted to use a multi line literal for ease of writing, I went for your solution in the end because it is the best given the limitations of the technology, yes you're right maybe I could read it in from a file if it was a lot of text :)

Comment: there is an issue here you can vote on https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18095